# How to get images from frames of a gif video?

Tags: video, images, gif

I was wondering how to get the images of the frames of a `.gif` video?

Comment: If you want to edit the images afterward, how about GIMP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can [split the animation into frames](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#adjoin).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something web-based, you can upload a .gif to [Free Online Image Editor](http://www.online-image-editor.com/index.cfm), and go to Edit > Gif Only > Split Into Frames.

(I used to use another site, GifWorks.com, for this, but I just now found out their site was hijacked or sold or something. It's a shame; it really was a good web application.)